# How to count from 1 to 25 in 5 lines with 5 numbers on each line

Tags: java

I am taking high-school computer science. We are supposed to do this and we have been teached nothing that would allow us to do this yet. How do I make a program that counts from 1 to 25 in 5 lines? Whatever I have made, is horribly inefficient and doesn't work anyway.

```
public class sumaverage {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(int count = 1; count < 22; count=count+5) {
        System.out.print(count); 
    }
    for(int count = 2; count < 23; count=count+5) {
        System.out.print(" " + count); 
    }
    for(int count = 3; count < 24; count=count+5) {
        System.out.print("   " + count); 
    }
    for(int count = 4; count < 25; count=count+5) {
        System.out.print("     " + count); 
    }
    for(int count = 5; count < 26; count=count+5) {
        System.out.print("     " + count); 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a loop that goes from 1 to 25 and a go to a new line once you've reached 5 numbers on the line.

With this algorithm, you should be able to produce the code.

Comment: Show us the expected output.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways of doing this. One is with a nested loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        System.out.print((i * 5 + j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Another is by using the modulo operator:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(i + " "); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop to count from 1 to 25.
Inside the for loop use an if statement to check if the value of i is a multiple of 5. This can be done by using the modulus operator(%) which returns zero if the number is a multiple of 5. If true, print a new line.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)         //count from 1 to 25 
    {
        System.out.print(i + " ");   //print i  plus space 

        if(i % 5 == 0){              // if i is a multiple of 5

           System.out.println();     //print new line 

       }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    Try this. 

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 6; j <=10 ; j++) {
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 11; j <=15 ; j++) {
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 16; j <=20 ; j++) {
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 21; j <=25 ; j++) {
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: add some description here